# how can i refer to a value in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, typescript, commonjs

server.ts

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var fs = require('fs');


import WonServer = require('./WonServer');

var server = new WonServer.WonServer();
```

WonServer.ts

```
export class WonServer {
    constructor() {
    }
    load() {
        console.log("loaded");
        io.emit('userlist', "asdsadsad");
    }
    sendMessage( msgtype:string, data:string) {
        io.emit(msgtype, data);
    }
}
```

Hi I am making a server in node.js

How to refer a value io(socket.io) in WonServer.js

Comment: Pass in io in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

General Principle

For each file that needs to use a dependency, there should be a `require` statement, or a constructor accepting an argument of the required type.

Unless you demand an argument by having a parameter on your constructor function, you can't rely on a file higher up in the hierarchy loading a dependency for you - so you ask for it explicitly. If the file is already in memory, it won't be loaded again, so the second access will be very fast.

Specific Answer

In your case, you could ask for it in the constructor.

```
export class WonServer {
    constructor(private io: SocketIOStatic) {
    }
    load() {
        console.log("loaded");
        this.io.emit('userlist', "asdsadsad");
    }
    sendMessage( msgtype:string, data:string) {
        this.io.emit(msgtype, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with this answer, also worth mentioning in case it isn't obvious: `var server = new WonServer(io);`